# google maps doesn't work in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive

GoogleMapsAPI implementation doesn't publish the map in the directory template.
Here is the markup and code

```
<gmap-locator></gmap-locator>
```

.

```
app.directive('gmapLocator', function () {
    var link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var map, mapOptions, markers;
                var lat = scope.mapParameters.initialSettings.Lat;
                var lng = scope.mapParameters.initialSettings.Lng;
                mapOptions = {
                    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                    zoom: scope.mapParameters.initialSettings.zoom
                };


                function initMap() {
                    if (map === void 0) {
                        map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);

                    }
                }
                initMap();
            }
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {
                    mapParameters: '='
                },
                template: "<div id='gomap' style='height: 400px;width:300px'></div>",
                controller: controller,
                link: link
            }
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                template: '<div id="gomap" style="width: 450px;height:400px;"></div>',
                link: link
            };
        });
```

Google Maps library doesn't detect the target div and publish the map..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is happening because `<div id="gomap"..` is published a child element to the directive element
 `<gmap-locator map-parameters="mapParameters"></gmap-locator>`
So the GoogleMaps initialization code in the initmap function should be changed to

```
map = new google.maps.Map(element[0].children[0], mapOptions);
```

or simple use `document.getElementById('gomap')` instead of using the element `parameter(element[0]`).

or the other way is to use replace: true within the directive return

```
return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                replace: true,
                ....
```

But it looks like AngularJS has depreciated the replace option.